# function doesn't catch error from calling nodejs / express server endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, post

I have this route set up on my server with nodejs/express:

```
const testSync = (req, res) => {
  //bookingLink and requestOptions defined here
  fetch(bookingLink , requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => {
      res.sendStatus(200)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error)
      res.sendStatus(404)
    });
}

router.post('/test-sync', testSync);
```

And here is my client side call :

```
 const requestOptions = {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
   body: JSON.stringify({url: `${bookingLink}`})
 }

 fetch(`${protocol}//${domainName}/api/test-sync`, requestOptions)
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then(result => {
     setSyncTest("success")
   })
   .catch(error => {
     setSyncTest("fail")
   });
```

The point of the client side call is to change the state of `syncTest` hook to "fail" if the link provided to the endpoint is bad. Now, if the link is bad it shows me the 404 error code in the console, but the `syncTest` doesn't change. I think it doesn't throw the error. How should I do to throw the error in order to change the hook state ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your function to:

```
const testSync = (req, res) => {
  //bookingLink and requestOptions defined here
  return fetch(bookingLink , requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => {
      res.sendStatus(200)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error)
      res.sendStatus(404)
    });
}

router.post('/test-sync', testSync);
```

You need to return your fetch request, which is a Promise. What is happening now is that your function is returning right away before fetch is complete.

or more direct/cleaner layout:

```js
const testSync = (req, res) => fetch(bookingLink , requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => res.sendStatus(200))
  .catch(error => {
     console.log('error', error)
     res.sendStatus(404)
  });

router.post('/test-sync', testSync);
```

### Client

Your client code is not handling the 404 correctly. Based on the instructions at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) an HTTP 404 or even a 500 will not reject the promise. You will need to handle them in the `then()`.

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my client side function still doesn't catch the error to change my hookstate into "fail". Something migh be wrong on the client side function ?

Comment: Are you able to test the request using Insomnia or Postman? This way you can test the end point separate from the front end.